# Global Variables - Page 0 or Application Item? [APEX 21.2]

Tags: oracle-apex

Just curious if there is a best practice when wanting to use global variables across an APEX application. Do people use APEX's APPLICATION_ITEMS or just add PAGE_ITEMS to the Global Page (Page 0)? My initial thought is to use APPLICATION_ITEMS since that is their intended purpose, but using Page 0 gets around the small extra step when having to reference an APPLICATION_ITEM from JavaScript.

Any performance issues or potential caveats I may hit either way that I may not be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, **Page 0** items are useful if you want to **display** the same contents on different pages so that you wouldn't have to maintain *many items* everywhere, but only on Page 0. If you want to use them as "invisible" global variables, you'd then have to hide them using a server-side condition or dynamic action. But, why would you then use Page 0 items? Use application items instead!

**Application items** are *true* global variables; they aren't displayed anywhere in the application, but contain values you use wherever you need them. Not that you *can't* display their values - you can, but that's not the issue we're discussing here.

I haven't noticed any performance issues while using any of these.

Comment: Those are my thoughts as well, but just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything. As always, thanks Littlefoot.

Comment: A typical use for P0 items for me is to have them hidden, with onChange DAs present